# How do I sort out my window sinc low pass filter

Tags: lowpass-filter, java, sinc

I started writing a windowed sinc low pass filter, but I cannot seam to get the code figured out right.

I followed these two links
http://doctord.webhop.net/Courses/textbooks/Smith_DSP/dsp_book_Ch16.pdf
and
https://tomroelandts.com/articles/how-to-create-a-simple-low-pass-filter

Thanks to @aconcerned It now only has one problem,
The waveforms are not normalised and I would like them to be.
I want them to maintain a somewhat constant amplitude no matter how much they filter.

Filtering to fundamental (I expect more falloff here due to band limit):
[image]
Filtering to 4th harmonic:
[image]
Filtering to 10kh:
[image]

I tried this filter on square and sawtooth waves so far. I am building it for resampling on a new music tracker format that I am coding.

Filter

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package effects;

/**
 *
 * @author Edward Jenkins
 */
public class SincLowPassFilter {

    public static final double DEF_BAND = 0;

    // instance variables
    private double cutoffFrequency;
    private double sampleRate;
    private double value;
    private double sumnatedValue;
    private double cutoffAmount;
    private double transitionBand;
    private double window;
    private double[] impulseResponce;
    private double[] sampleCache;
    private int sampleCacheLength;
    private int n;
    private int order;
    private int midPoint;

    // constructor
    public SincLowPassFilter(double cutoffFrequency, double sampleRate, 
            int band) {
        this.cutoffFrequency = cutoffFrequency;
        cutoffAmount = cutoffFrequency  / sampleRate;
        transitionBand = band / sampleRate;
        n = (int)(Math.ceil(4 / transitionBand));
        
        // make sure length is odd
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n += 1;
        }
        order = n - 1;
        midPoint = order / 2;
        impulseResponce = new double[n];
        sumnatedValue = 0;

        // get window of filtering
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            
            impulseResponce[i] = cutoffAmount 
                    * sinc(2 * cutoffAmount * Math.PI * (i - midPoint));
            
            impulseResponce[midPoint] = cutoffAmount;

            window = 0.54 - 0.46 * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / order);
            
            impulseResponce[i] *= window;
        }
        
        // sumnate all filter kernal values
        double sum = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {    
            sum += impulseResponce[i];
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {    
            impulseResponce[i] /= sum;
            impulseResponce[i] *= 1.2;
        }

        sampleCache = new double[n];
        sampleCacheLength = 0;
    }

    // low pass filter
    public void inputPoint(double point) {
        
        value = 0;
        /*value = impulseResponce[sampleCacheLength];
        
        if (sampleCacheLength >= n-1) {
            sampleCacheLength = 0;
        } else {
            sampleCacheLength++;
        }*/
        
        if (sampleCacheLength < n) {
            
            sampleCache[sampleCacheLength] = point;
            sampleCacheLength++;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; i++, j--) {
                value += sampleCache[j] * impulseResponce[i];
            }
            incrementCache(point);
        }
    }
    
    private void incrementCache(double value) {
        
        for(int i = 0; i < sampleCacheLength - 1; i++) {
            sampleCache[i] = sampleCache[i + 1];
        }
        sampleCache[sampleCacheLength - 1] = value;
    }
    
    // can low pass
    public boolean canLowPass() {
        boolean result = false;
        
        if (sampleCacheLength >= n) {
            result = true;
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    // sinc
    public double sinc(double value) {
        if (value == 0) {
            value = 1;
        } else {
            value = Math.sin(value) / value;
        }
        return value;
    }
    
    public double lowPass() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Execution

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sound.generator;

import effects.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import sound.generator.waveforms.*;
import sound.formatter.*;
import music.note.NoteRange;

/**
 *
 * @author Edward Jenkins
 */
public class SoundGenerator {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NoteRange noteRange = new NoteRange(451, "C-1", "C9");
        double frequency = noteRange.getFrequency("C4");
        int sampleRate = 44100;
        int bitRate = 16;
        byte[] outputBytes;
        double duration = 5;

        // harmoncis
        double[] harmonicVolumes = {1, 0, 1, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.09, 0, 0.08, 0, 0.07};

        SawtoothGenerator sg = new SawtoothGenerator(frequency, 0);
        try {
            Celeste c = new Celeste(1, true, true, true, 0.75, sg);
            AdsrEnvelope ae = new AdsrEnvelope(1, 0.05, 0.2, true, 0.8, 0.25, sampleRate);
            Vibrato v = new Vibrato(0.66, 0.125, frequency, 0, sampleRate);
            Tremulant t = new Tremulant(0.66, 0.75, 0.5, sampleRate, false);
            SincLowPassFilter lpf = new SincLowPassFilter(261.63 * 6, sampleRate, 400);
            int sampleLength = (int) (duration * sampleRate);
            AmpLimiter al = new AmpLimiter(bitRate, false);
            double point;
            double[] points = new double[sampleLength];
            double pointVolume;

            for (int exportIndex = 0; exportIndex < sampleLength; exportIndex++) {
                if (exportIndex == sampleRate * 4) {
                    ae.setSustain(false);
                }
                //sg.setFrequency(v.getVibratoFrequency(exportIndex));
                point = c.detune();
                lpf.inputPoint(point);
                if (lpf.canLowPass()) {
                    point = lpf.lowPass();
                    pointVolume = ae.getADSRvolume(exportIndex);
                    //pointVolume *= t.drawTremulantPoint(pointVolume, ae.getSustainStartPoint());
                    sg.setAmplitude(pointVolume);
                    points[exportIndex] = point;
                    points[exportIndex] = al.calculateAmpLimit(points[exportIndex]);
                } else {
                    exportIndex--;
                }
                /*pointVolume = ae.getADSRvolume(exportIndex);
                //pointVolume *= t.drawTremulantPoint(pointVolume, ae.getSustainStartPoint());
                c.setAmplitudes(pointVolume);
                points[exportIndex] = point;
                points[exportIndex] = al.calculateAmpLimit(points[exportIndex]);*/

            }

            IWriteWave ww = new WriteWave(1, 44100, bitRate, points, "LPF Sawtooth C4",
                    false);

            try {
                ww.writeWav();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Despite my efforts I could not understand your problem. But I see one potential error, passing zero to `sinc`  as far as I know  `(n - 1) / 2` will compute an integer division, and `sinc(0) = 1`.

Comment: I have deduced that the either the sinc or the window function are wrong. also if I set N to 100. I can get better results.

Comment: The function generating the impulse response is wrong. After calculating it, try setting `h[floor(N/2)] *= 2`. Either that or halven the others, I can't tell which one is wrong, but that's where the difference is. Also, not sure if it's halvened, but you can easily check that `h[floor(N/2)]` should be equal to `wp`. If you have acces to the raw `sinc()` function, use it as `wp*sinc(wp*k)`. Window optional.

Comment: Could you please explain using the variables I have in my code?

Comment: @a concerned citizen Do you mean by my code, ```filterKernal[(int)Math.floor(n / 2)] *= 2;```? Also should it be done before or after the sumnation?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen My Bad, I meant ```filterKernal[(int)Math.floor(i / 2)] *= 2;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not good in Java, but it looks like you defined your `sinc()` below with `sin(x)/x`, no checks, then you are using it in your calculations as:

```
h[n]=sinc(2*f*n)=sin(2*f*n)/(2*f*n)
```

Then you are using `i-(n-1)/2` for your sinc but the check is for `i-n/2`. And your window is calculated as:

```
w[n]=0.54-0.46*cos(2*pi*n*(N-1))
```

I won't question your way of calculating the order, but if I got it right and this is how you're calculating them, you're not doing a good job. What you call the filter "kernal" (it's spelled *kernel*, BTW) is the impulse response. This, and the window (Hamming, by the looks of it) are calculated as:

$$\begin{align}
h[n]&=\omega_p\mathrm{sinc}(\pi\omega_p(n-M))=\dfrac{\sin(\omega_p\pi(n-M))}{\pi(n-M)}\tag{1} \\
w[n]&=0.54-0.46\cos(2\pi\dfrac{n}{N})\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Where $\omega_p$ is the normalized corner (cut-off) frequency, $N$ is the order, $M=N/2$, and $n=0,\,1,\,...\,,\,N$. With these you can define sinc as:

```
if(x == 0)
  return 1.0;
else
  return sin(pi*x)/(pi*x);
```

and use it as `wp*sinc(wp*n)` to calculate the impulse response. Then, the window:

```
0.54-0.46*cos(2*pi*x/N)
```

where `N` is the order (how did you come up with that formula for calculating the order?). Note, not the *length* (`L`, number of taps), not the *middle point* (`M`, order divided by 2): `N=L-1, M=N/2`.

To test this, I used Octave (`%` denote a comment):

```
L=33;         % length of the filter
N=L-1;        % order
M=N/2;        % mid point
n=[0:N];
w0=2;         % sampling frequency
wp=200/512;   % corner (cut-off) frequency, chosen to match the grid, below
% impulse response, h[n]
% h=wp*sinc(wp*(n-M));   % this is the built-in function
h=sin(wp*pi*(n-M))./(pi*(n-M));
h(M+1)=wp;   % NOTE: Octave starts the index at 1, for you it will be h[M]
% Hamming window
$ w=hamming(L);   % this is the buit-in function
w=0.54-0.46*cos(2*pi*n/N);
w(M+1)=1;   % for you it will be w[M], see the NOTE above
% test the frequency response
H=fft(h.*w,1024)(1:512);
subplot(1,2,1); plot(h,"",w); subplot(1,2,2); plot(20*log10(abs(H)));
```

[image: test]

Comment: You code has solved most of the problems, but the waveform is not normalised. Before it maintained a constant amplitude, but not is gets softer the more you filter.

Comment: @EdwardEddy67716 What do you mean it gets softer? Plot your impulse response in Audacious and perform an FFT on it. It should show a correct lowpass filter like in my image. If the results are the same, then the problem is elsewhere. Maybe in the code with the actual filtering.

Comment: Actually it is not that noticeable.

Comment: Is there a way I can apply resonance to this filter like one can to a Two pole filter?

Comment: @EdwardEddy67716 Sounds like you need an IIR.

Comment: I just wanted to know. In case I could use it as an optional instead of a two pole filter.

Comment: How would I convert this into a High Pass filter?

Comment: @EdwardEddy67716 You need either frequency transformations, or a different transfer function for the bilinear transform, but better ask a new question for that.

Comment: I did it by doing this ```value = Math.sin(value) / (value) + resonance *  Math.sin(value);```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the whole thing to work.

Code to do so:

````
/**
 *
 * @author Edward Jenkins
 * @version 1.2
 */
public abstract class SincSpecs implements ISimpleFilter{
    
    // instance variables
    private double cutoffFrequency;
    private double sampleRate;
    private double resonance;
    private boolean highPass;
    private double value;
    private double sumnatedValue;
    private double cutoffAmount;
    private double transitionBand;
    private double window;
    private double[] impulseResponce;
    private double[] sampleCache;
    private int sampleCacheLength;
    private int n;
    private int order;
    private int midPoint;
    //private int index;
    
    // constructor
    public SincSpecs(double cutoffFrequency, double sampleRate, byte resonance,
            boolean highPass, int band, ISample sample) {
        this.cutoffFrequency = cutoffFrequency;
        this.resonance = (double)resonance / 127;
        this.highPass = highPass;
        this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
        cutoffAmount = cutoffFrequency  / this.sampleRate;
        transitionBand = band / sampleRate;
        //index = 0;
        n = (int)(Math.ceil(4 / transitionBand));
        
        // make sure length is odd
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n += 1;
        }
        order = n;
        midPoint = order / 2 + 1;
        impulseResponce = new double[n];
        sumnatedValue = 0;

        updateImpulseResponce();

        sampleCache = new double[n];
        sampleCacheLength = 0;

        double inputPoint = sample.generateWaveformPoint();

        while (!canOutput()) {
            inputFilterPoint(inputPoint);
        }
    }
    
    public double getTransitionBand() {
        return transitionBand;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setCutoff(double cutoffFrequency) {
        
        this.cutoffFrequency = cutoffFrequency;
        cutoffAmount = this.cutoffFrequency / sampleRate;
        updateImpulseResponce();
    }
    
    public void updateImpulseResponce() {
        
        // get window of filtering
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            
            impulseResponce[i] = cutoffAmount 
                    * sinc(2 * cutoffAmount * Math.PI * (i - midPoint));
            
            impulseResponce[midPoint] = cutoffAmount;

            window = 0.54 - 0.46 * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / order);
            
            impulseResponce[i] *= window;
        }
        
        // sumnate all filter kernal values
        double sum = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {    
            sum += impulseResponce[i];
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {    
            impulseResponce[i] /= sum;
        }
        
        // invert the impulse responce if high pass is true
        if (this.highPass) {
            invertImpulseForHighPass();
        }
    }
    
    // input points
    protected void inputFilterPoint(double point) {

        sampleCache[sampleCacheLength] = point;
        sampleCacheLength++;

        for (int i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; i++, j--) {
            value += sampleCache[j] * impulseResponce[i];
        }
    }

    protected void incrementCache(double value) {

        for (int i = 0; i < sampleCacheLength - 1; i++) {
            sampleCache[i] = sampleCache[i + 1];
        }
        sampleCache[sampleCacheLength - 1] = value;
    }

    // can output
    protected boolean canOutput() {
        boolean result = false;

        if (sampleCacheLength == n) {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    // sinc
    protected double sinc(double value) {
        if (value == 0) {
            value = 1;
        } else {
            value = Math.sin(value) / (value) + resonance *  Math.sin(value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    protected void invertImpulseForHighPass() {

        for (int i = 0; i < impulseResponce.length; i++) {
            impulseResponce[i] *= -1;
        }
        impulseResponce[midPoint] += 1;
    }

    @Override
    public double filter(double point) {

        //index++;
        
        value = 0;

        for (int i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; i++, j--) {
            value += sampleCache[j] * impulseResponce[i];
        }
        incrementCache(point);
        
        /*if (index == n) {
            index = 0;
        }*/

        return value;
    }
}
```
````